# Computing Riemann integral (if you know the integral of a similar function)

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Suppose I have a function f, that differs from another function g by exactly one point, let's say at c.

I know that I can conclude that f is Riemann integrable on [a,b] if g is on the same interval. Now, my question is : so we have c in [a,b] and we know that the Riemann integral of g on our interval is 0, can I conclude the same thing for f ?

I know other ways to work with Riemann integrability such as the squeeze theorem, but I want to know if this would be a valid shortcut in our situation.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If $f$ and $g$ differ only on a set of measure $0$, which any finite set is, then $\int fdx=\int gdx$. Since $f$ and $g$ differ only at a single point $c$ in your example, the upper and lower sums of $f$ and $g$ will be the same and so their integral will be the same if $g$ is Riemann integrable.

More detailed version:
Let $g$ be a Riemann integrable function on $[a,b]$ and let $f$ be a function defined on $[a,b]$ with $g(x)=f(x)\quad \forall x\in[a,c)\cup(c,b]$. Since $g$ is Riemann integrable, $U(g)=L(g)=\int_a^b g(x)dx$ is defined. Since $f$ and $g$ differ only at a single point, $U(g)=U(f)=L(g)=L(f)$. Thus, $\int_a^b f(x)dx=U(f)=U(g)=\int_a^bg(x)dx$. So $f$ is Riemann integrable and $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bg(x)dx$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer ! What do you mean by a set of measure 0 ? Because there is one element in that set, it's not empty. Would that be related to the width of a potential interval where f and g differ ? (in our case width 0)

Comment: @ThéodoreRozencwajg Sets of measure $0$ include things like all finite finite or countable sets of the reals.

Comment: I should not have used the word measure if you have not yet gone over that in class. For your purposes, we will get the same conclusion by considering the set that $f$ and $g$ differ on to be finite and discrete.

Comment: Okay makes sense, thank you ! I am not sure we covered upper and lower sums in class so I guess I shouldn't use this shortcut to find the interval right ? It's probably better to use the Squeeze theorem and the definition of Riemann integrability, what do you think ?

Comment: If you haven't gone over Upper and Lower sums then you should not use them without defining them and their properties which will be a lot of work.

Comment: Okay, does this result hold if f differs from g from countably many points, or does it have to be 1 ?

Comment: No it can be infinite as long as it is countable. The true restriction is that the set should be measure zero which effectively means countable and without limit points.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ differs from $g$ at only one point then you have that $f(x)-g(x)=0$ at all except one point so you have $\int_{a}^{b}(f(x)-g(x))dx=0$ so their integrals are the same number because of $\int_{a}^{b}(f(x)-g(x))dx=0=\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx - \int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx$ so we have $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx$.

You could use exactly the same argument if $f$ differs from $g$ at some finite number of points, but if they differ in an infinite number of points the situation may become different, depending on whether the infinite number of points is countable or uncountable set.

Comment: Thank you very much, I get it !